# Change the height and width of sheerui sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am looking everywhere but with no success. What I need to do is to change the height and width of sitecore sheerui.

Anyone has an idea?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<control xmlns:def="Definition" xmlns="http://schemas.sitecore.net/Visual-Studio-Intellisense">
  <RichText.InsertPopupText>
    <FormDialog Icon="Network/32x32/link.png" Header="Insert an Popuptext" Text="Insert the Popup text code to Insert." OKButton="Insert" >
      <script Type="text/javascript" Language="javascript" Src="Controls/Rich Text Editor/InsertPopupText/InsertPopupText.js">.</script>
      <CodeBeside Type="Accenture.Online.SitecoreExtensions.XMLControls.InsertPopupText,Accenture.Online.SitecoreExtensions"/>

      <GridPanel Width="100%" Height="100%" >
        <label ID="lblHeader">Popup text</label>
        <Memo ID="memCode" Style="height:100%;width:100%;border-top:1px solid #919b9c" ></Memo>
        <label ID="lblDescription">Description</label>
        <Memo ID="memDescription" Style="height:100%;width:100%;border-top:1px solid #919b9c" ></Memo>  
       </GridPanel>
    </FormDialog>
  </RichText.InsertPopupText>
</control>
```

Comment: Do you want to increase height of your sheer ui dialog window ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are `Height` and `Width` fields in the application definition item in the `Core` database. 
This is typically located somewhere like `Sitecore/Content/Applications/YourApplication`

if you're opening your dialog with javascript from the RTE, then here is an example of where and how you can set the width and height

```javascript
RadEditorCommandList["MyCommand"] = function(commandName, editor, tool) 
{
    scEditor = editor; 

    scEditor.showExternalDialog(
        "/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=RichText.MyControl",
        null,
        270, //width  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        350, //height <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        scInsertThing,
        null,
        "My app",
        true, 
        Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close,
        false, 
        false);
};
```

This example comes from a working application.

Comment: Can you ellaborate more?But I want to change the specific height and width for this only?

Comment: View the core database in the content editor and go to the path I specified above. You should see an item something like (I assume) "Insert popup text". The height and width fields will be in there.

Comment: I created this Insert popup text like the one describe below. How do i do the above? http://www.markstiles.net/Blog/2012/02/17/adding-button-to-rich-text-editor-in-sitecore-6-4.aspx

Comment: Ok, in this case height and width are set from the command javascript code that opens the dialog (it's shown in the article you referenced). I have added some code to my answer which comes from one of my own working applications.

Comment: Can the width be specified in percentage or does it always need to be in pixels?

Comment: Pixels only I believe.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I have a question.  I am trying to change the height of my dialog and it seems like Sitecore is ignoring any changes I make to this file.  I changed the height from 600 to 100 but it doesn't change at all.  I have recycled the app pool also but it never changes.  Any ideas?